# Calculate MAX for every row in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this tables:

- `Docenza(id, id_facolta, ..., orelez)`
- `Facolta(id, ...)`

and I want to obtain, for every facolta, only the id of Docenza who has done the maximum number of orelez and the number of orelez:

```
id_docenzaP  facolta1   max(orelez)
id_docenzaQ  facolta2   max(orelez)
...
id_docenzaZ  facoltaN   max(orelez)
```

how can I do this? This is what i do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ... F.nome, SUM(orelez) AS oreTotali
FROM Docenza D 
  JOIN Facolta F ON F.id = D.id_facolta
GROUP BY F.nome
```

I obtain somethings like:

```
 docenzaP  facolta1   maxValueForidP
 docenzaQ  facolta1   maxValueForidQ
 ...
 docenzaR  facolta2   maxValueForidR
 docenzaS  facolta2   maxValueForidS
 ...
 docenzaZ  facoltaN   maxValueForFacoltaN
```

How can I take only the max value for every facolta?

Comment: Your use of max with sum is confusing to me.  Can you edit your question and post actual data, instead of text placeholders?

Comment: You should add sample data and your expected result. Your description and code don't match up.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you just want:

```
SELECT F.nome, sum(orelez) AS oreTotali
FROM Docenza D JOIN
     Facolta F
     ON F.id = D.id_facolta
GROUP BY F.nome;
```

I'm not sure what the `SELECT DISTINCT` is supposed to be doing.  It is almost never used with `GROUP BY`.  The `. . .` suggests that you are selecting additional columns, which are not needed for the results you want.

Comment: Why Sum instead of Max? Sum is going to add up all the values in that table, when he's asking for the Max value in the table. The rest of your comment is spot on, but that piece doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Patrick . . . I followed the code that was written, rather than the description.  The question is more confusing when I read it more carefully.

Comment: Ok - that makes more sense. I agree, very confusing question.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, and since you didn't provide sample data with expected results I can't be sure it's really what you need.

It's a bit ugly and I'm sure there is some clever correlated sub query approach, but I've never been good with those.

```
SELECT st.focolta,
       s_orelez,
       TMP3.id_docenza
  FROM some_table AS st
 INNER
  JOIN (SELECT * 
          FROM (SELECT focolta,
                       s_orelez,
                       id_docenza,
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER -- Get the ranking of the orelez sum by focolta.
                         ( PARTITION BY focolta
                               ORDER BY s_orelez DESC
                         ) rn_orelez
                  FROM (SELECT focolta,
                               id_docenza,
                               SUM(orelez) OVER -- Sum the orelez by focolta
                                ( PARTITION BY focolta
                                ) AS s_orelez 
                          FROM some_table
                       ) TMP
               ) TMP2 
         WHERE = TMP2.rn_orelez = 1 -- Limit to the highest rank value
       ) TMP3
    ON some_table.focolta = TMP3.focolta; -- Join to focolta to the id associated with the hightest value.
```